# How to find and update deprecated API in GKE cluster?

Tags: api, google-kubernetes-engine

Can't find where exactly we use deprecated API
[image: warning about deprecation]

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________
>>> Deprecated APIs removed in 1.22 <<<
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KIND                       NAMESPACE     NAME                                           API_VERSION                    REPLACE_WITH (SINCE)
CustomResourceDefinition   <undefined>   capacityrequests.internal.autoscaling.k8s.io   apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1   apiextensions.k8s.io/v1 (1.16.0)
```

So i think problem with [API CustomResourceDefinition](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-22?_gl=1*tj8w9o*_ga*MjA2MDE0NzUwOS4xNjg1NzEyODM1*_ga_WH2QY8WWF5*MTY4NjI5MjIwMC4xNi4xLjE2ODYyOTI3OTQuMC4wLjA.&_ga=2.149260469.-2060147509.1685712835#customresourcedefinition-v122), but i have no idea how to fix

Why i see in web ui this API `/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterrolebindings`?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the notification is based on usage from the last 30 days. If the 1.22 upgrade happened in the last 30 days, you’ll continue seeing these notifications. In addition, if the last observed date of an deprecated API usage happened after the cluster is upgraded to 1.22, this means the deprecated APIs are still being called and these calls will result in failures. Customers need to [take actions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-22#update-clusters) on these API clients which are making deprecated API calls and migrate these clients so that they use the v1 version.

As per this official [Deprecated API Migration Guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#customresourcedefinition-v122),

> Warning: If you do not update a client or manifest before the 1.22
> upgrade, it will not be able to read/modify existing objects or create
> new objects. The client or manifest will only be able to read, modify,
> or create objects once you update it.

- For [Custom Resource definition](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-22#customresourcedefinition-v122), Migrate manifests and API
  clients use the apiextensions.k8s.io/v1 API version.
- As per this can you please try to migrate manifest and API Clients by
  looking into the notable changes mentioned in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-22?_gl=1*tj8w9o*_ga*MjA2MDE0NzUwOS4xNjg1NzEyODM1*_ga_WH2QY8WWF5*MTY4NjI5MjIwMC4xNi4xLjE2ODYyOTI3OTQuMC4wLjA.&_ga=2.149260469.-2060147509.1685712835#customresourcedefinition-v122).
- You are also getting this URL
  apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterrolebindings as this
  got  deprecated. Do the necessary changes to this URL by following
  this [RBAC resources guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#rbac-resources-v122) .
- To know more insights about deprecated API and its alternate use,
  follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/viewing-deprecation-insights-and-recommendations).
- You can also refer to the doc [Preparing to upgrade to version 1.22](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-22#preparing_to_upgrade_to_version_122) .